# Find $\tan(\alpha+\beta)$ when $\tan \beta = \frac{n\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{1-n\cos^2\alpha}$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Given, $$\tan \beta = \frac{n\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{1-n\cos^2\alpha}$$
>   Then $\tan(\alpha + \beta)$ is equal to
>
> 1. $(n-1)\tan\alpha$
> 2. $(n+1)\tan\alpha$
> 3. $\frac{\tan\alpha}{n+1}$
> 4. $\frac{\tan\alpha}{1-n}$

I would also appreciate practical methods of tackling problems such as this in competitive examinations.

Comment: Do you know of the addition formula for the tangent function?

Comment: @mickep You mean: $$\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you knew about the addition formula for tan, here is a push in the right direction:

I think it will be easier if one first simplifies $\tan\beta$,
$$
\tan\beta=\frac{n\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{1-n\cos^2\alpha}=\frac{n\tan\alpha}{1/\cos^2\alpha-n}=\frac{n\tan\alpha}{\tan^2\alpha+1-n}.
$$
Next, use the addition formula for $\tan(\alpha+\beta)$ and insert the expression above everywhere you encounter $\tan\beta$. Simplify, and you got your result.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked for me. But I was wondering if there was  any quicker way to do it... (assumptions and short-cuts allowed).

Answer (score 1):

A quicker method would be to substitute a simple value for $\alpha$ such as $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and do the same compound angle formula simplification

Comment: I agree that is a bit simpler, given that one of the four alternatives really is correct.